# Appending new elements into an empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, web

Im facing issue with appending new elements into list. In first SS the data is shown which means it is present but when Im appending the data in a loop, the data shown is Nan. Please refer to the screen shots.

[Data showing (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86U5d.png)

```
result_items[0]['Media'][0]['Description']
```

[Result NaN (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHzxi.png)

```
for result in result_items:
    try:
            media_description.append(result[0]['Media'][0]['Description'])
    except:
            media_description.append(np.nan)   

media_description
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images.

Comment: In the first case you are getting the "first" item. in the second you use a for loop to get each item so you don't want to use the first index.  Try `result["Media"][0]["Description"]`. Also you probably don't want to catch all exceptions like you are as it makes it harder to figure out where stuff breaks. If you have dictionaries with potentially missing keys, check out `.get()`

Comment: Thank you so much JonSG. It worked. I'll make sure to post the code as well in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 2nd image/cell of code, you are using `result[0]` whereas `result` itself is the element of the list, so there was no need to subscript the element.

Replacing the line in 2nd cell with the following will fix the issue

```
media_description.append(result['Media'][0]['Description'])
```